# Browserify + vue + HTML minify

Tags: gulp, vue.js, laravel-elixir, gulp-minify

I'm using `elixir` together with `browserify`. In my vue components I include templates from html files, like this:

```js
Vue.extend({
    template: require('./call.html'),
    props: {
        call: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },
    //...
```

It works as expected. However, if I run `gulp --production`, the html is not compressed in the generated file.

What I'd like to achieve is to remove all unneeded tab, space, newline characters, comments from the included html files.

There's a package called [gulp-minify-html](https://github.com/murphydanger/gulp-minify-html) but I don't know how if I could use this one for solving this issue.

Has anyone here done something similar to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [vueify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vueify).
Minification is automatically applied on template, when compiled with NODE_ENV=production.

You won't need to place your html in separate file in that case, as well.
But you could if needed: just omit `<template>` block and add template to module.exports object as usual:

```
<script>
    module.exports = {
        template: require('./template1.html'),
    };
</script>
```

## Research

So, in fact its minification is purely decorational.
As follows from dependencies list, vueify depends on [html-minifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier).

Let's take a look at code:

```
// production minifiers
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  var htmlMinifier = require('html-minifier')
  // required for Vue 1.0 shorthand syntax
  var htmlMinifyOptions = {
    customAttrSurround: [[/@/, new RegExp('')], [/:/, new RegExp('')]]
  }
}
```

The only option here is `customAttrSurround`, thus, anything else will be taken from [default](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier#options-quick-reference) values.

## Result

We have several options here:

1. Fix the source once. Just add your config [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vueify/blob/master/lib/compiler.js#L14).
2. Create an issue on github. Minifier config surely must be included in vue.config.js.
3. Pull request.

## Final solution by asker

The code above should be replaced by this:

```
// production minifiers
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  var htmlMinifier = require('html-minifier')
  // required for Vue 1.0 shorthand syntax
  var htmlMinifyOptions = {
    customAttrSurround: [[/@/, new RegExp('')], [/:/, new RegExp('')]],
    collapseWhitespace: true,
    removeComments: true
  }
}
```

See my [pull request](https://github.com/vuejs/vueify/pull/42)

Comment: Thanks! Will it also work if I still want to store html in a separate file?

Comment: HI! Thanks for your hint. I tried it out and it only removes unnecessary whitespace characters from the beginning and the end. I use a package called `laravel-elixir-vueify` and I compiled the example source provided here: https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-Elixir-Vueify-Setup . I made a diff to demonstrate this: http://i.imgur.com/GsnFKkp.png . On the right NODE_ENV=production is turned on, while on the left, it's not. The `--production` option on gulp has no effect on this. However CSS is minified as excepted. But in HTML there are still unnecessary whitespaces

Comment: @balping let's dive in then. Check my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed work! I'll try to correct this bug

Comment: I made a pull request. It works for me at least. Thanks again! https://github.com/vuejs/vueify/pull/42

Comment: @balping Wow. Glad to be helpful. Fancy stuff. :3